# Performance of LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using Entity Framework 4 in a project, and I have one specific query that gets run over and over again that I need to be sure that is optimized as good as possible.

I have one database table called `Items` that have the following important columns:

```
id (primary key)
name
```

Another table called `FavoriteItems` has two important columns

```
itemId (foreign key to the items table)
accountId( foreign key to the account table)
```

In a method in my code, I have `accountId`, and a `searchTerm` as input parameters.

The method should return all items from the items table that has searchTerm as a part of it's name, in addition it should be sorted alphabetically, but all the items that has it's Id found in the FavoriteItems table where the accountId match the accountId given as parameter should be put on top (and sorted alphabetically). In addition, the searhc result should contain a boolean indicating whether it's a favorite item or not.

I have got it working, but the query seems clumsy. How would you write this query in an elegant and performant way?

Comment: Not necessarily an answer, but if the emphasis is that it is "optimized as good as possible", then *personally* I'd be writing this in TSQL. YMMV. Just sayin'...

Comment: Have you written the query and are you having performance issues or are you just being preemptive?

Comment: @marc-gravell Actually if you want to make sure the query is as optimized as possible, that's the best answer. :) There's some cases you simply need to go that route. I don't think there's enough info here to say for sure if this is one of those or not, but it's a totally valid answer.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - I hope that optimized as much as possible using LINQ will suffice, else I will have to go the TSQL way. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @BZink - No problems yet, but the site is not launched yet, and this is likely to be a bottleneck in it's current form.

Comment: If this is a specific query I would write store an optimized query in a SQL View and select from that in the relevant cases. I would also make sure to have the relevant indexes in place and make sure the query uses them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
public void TheMethod(int accountId, string searchTerm)
{
    var result = from item in ctx.Items
                 where item.Name.Contains(searchTerm)
                 let temp = new
                     {
                         Name = item.Name,
                         IsFavorite = item.FavoriteItems
                             .Any(f => f.AccountId == accountId)
                     }
                 orderby temp.IsFavorite descending, temp.Name
                 select temp;
}
```

Create an intermediate object with just the values you need, order that, and select it.

I don't think it can be optimized further, because you need all the items that have have `searchTerm` in the name. That's probably the most expensive parts as its converted to `WHERE Name LIKE %@name%`.

The `.Any` call that results `IsFavorite` field results in a `EXISTS SELECT TOP(1)...` type of query, and should be quite cheap.

Comment: This seems very good :) I will verify this when I get home later today, and mark as accepted if it works out well.

Comment: It worked as a charm. I'm not that familiar with the `let` keyword, but I certainly see where it can be useful in cases like this. Thanks a lot.